# Keep information through different pages

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

im using wpf c# to navigate between various pages and i was wondering how information can be used from 1 page to another, but im using also material design to accomplish this. Any ideas?

The code im using can be found on:
[MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/MainDemo.Wpf/TransitionsDemo/](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MainDemo.Wpf/TransitionsDemo)

Comment: What's stopping you from sharing your data object across pages? This sounds more like an issue with incorrect data binding than with the framework you are using.

Comment: You just need to use a state model like MVVM where your data has an independent life from your WPF controls/views. Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern

Comment: @TanveerBadar I literally used the same code provided in TransitionsDemo... the problem is that there are obviously ways to use navigation but I was wondering how data passing is done through the use of material design. Navigation is done by commands and they are part of the library. I was wondering if I could add additional logic to not only change pages, but after changing the page I would like to keep the information saved in page 1 within page 2.

Comment: Instead of posting code, error messages, data, or other text as images or links, please [edit] your post to copy/paste or type the actual text directly into the post (for code, use a [code block](/editing-help#code)). [Text in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue, and error messages in images cannot be searched](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links may become invalid if the linked site changes.  If your code is too long to fit in the post, we have tips on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Do you think about creating SharedDataService class? You can create singleton object of the service with needed properties and inject it where you need to use same instance of this service.

```
public class SharedDataService
{
    string SharedProperty {get; set;}
}
```

and now in you class you can use it like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SharedDataService _mySharedService;
    public MyClass(SharedDataService mySharedService)
    {
        _mySharedService = mySharedService;
    }

    public void UpdateSharedProperty()
    {
         SharedProperty = "New value from MyClass";
    }
}
```

This way you can access SharedDataService  from all needed classes.
If you don't like dependecy injection you can create static SharedDataService class.